# Angular 1 Build - Module not found

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp, yeoman

I'm working on a angular 1 application. All is good when running the `dev server` but when building and trying to serve the `prod serve` (from dist) i get a module not found error.

I created my project with yeoman for what it's worth.

My bower.json file:

```
{
  "name": "nqa",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.4.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.0.0",
    "angular-animate": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-cookies": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-messages": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-resource": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-route": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-sanitize": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-touch": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-ui-select": "^0.19.8",
    "angular-file-upload": "^2.5.0",
    "angular-bootstrap": "^2.5.0",
    "angular-clipboard": "^1.5.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "^1.4.0",
    "ng-image-cache": "^0.4.0"
  },
  "appPath": "app",
  "moduleName": "nqaApp",
  "overrides": {
    "bootstrap": {
      "main": [
        "less/bootstrap.less",
        "dist/css/bootstrap.css",
        "dist/js/bootstrap.js"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

My package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "nqa",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-file-upload": "^2.5.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "2.3.1",
    "gulp-babel": "^6.1.2",
    "gulp-cache": "^0.2.10",
    "gulp-connect": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-deploy-ftp": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-filter": "^2.0.2",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^2.3.0",
    "gulp-jshint": "^1.11.1",
    "gulp-karma": "0.0.4",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "^0.10.0",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-ng-annotate": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.0.1",
    "gulp-replace": "^0.5.4",
    "gulp-rev": "^5.0.1",
    "gulp-rev-replace": "^0.4.2",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-useref": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.8",
    "gulp-watch": "^4.2.4",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.5.2",
    "jshint-stylish": "^1.0.0",
    "karma": "^1.6.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.4",
    "lazypipe": "^0.2.4",
    "open": "0.0.5",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.14",
    "rimraf": "^2.4.0",
    "run-sequence": "^1.1.1",
    "vinyl-ftp": "^0.6.0",
    "wiredep": "^2.2.2",
    "yargs": "^8.0.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "karma start test\\karma.conf.js"
  }
}
```

Module injections from app.js, if somehow usefull:

```
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc overview
 * @name nqaApp
 * @description
 * # nqaApp
 *
 * Main module of the application.
 */
angular
    .module('nqaApp', [
        'ngAnimate',
        'ngCookies',
        'ngMessages',
        'ngResource',
        'ngRoute',
        'ngSanitize',
        'ngTouch',
        'angular-clipboard',
        'angularFileUpload',
        'ui.select',
    ])
    .config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
                controller: 'MainCtrl',
                controllerAs: 'main'
            })
            .when('/cities', {
                templateUrl: 'views/cities.html',
                controller: 'CitiesCtrl',
                controllerAs: 'cities'
            })
            .when('/locations/:cityId?', {
                templateUrl: 'views/locations.html',
                controller: 'LocationsCtrl',
                controllerAs: 'locations'
            })
            .when('/quests', {
              templateUrl: 'views/quests.html',
              controller: 'QuestsCtrl',
              controllerAs: 'quests'
            })
            .when('/clues/:questId?', {
              templateUrl: 'views/clues.html',
              controller: 'CluesCtrl',
              controllerAs: 'clues'
            })
            .when('/media', {
              templateUrl: 'views/media.html',
              controller: 'MediaCtrl',
              controllerAs: 'media'
            })
            .when('/demo', {
              templateUrl: 'views/demo.html',
              controller: 'DemoCtrl',
              controllerAs: 'demo'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
    });
```

Imports part from index.html:

```
<!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-messages/angular-messages.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-ui-select/dist/select.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-file-upload/dist/angular-file-upload.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-clipboard/angular-clipboard.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->

<!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/about.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/menu.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/cities.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/locations.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/services/locations.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/services/cities.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/services/base_url.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/filters/locations.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/quests.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/services/quests.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/clues.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/services/clues.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/directives/all.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/filters/quests.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/filters/clues.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/media.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/services/media.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/demo.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/directives/includableimage.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

The exact error i get:

[image: The exact error i get:]

What i've tried:
 - removing and resinstalling all packages
 - changing order of the modules in app.js

Comment: Can you post full app.js file with ur imports ?

Comment: @RahulNaik i've updated with the app.js with the full content and added the imports from index.html

Comment: Can you check if script path for angular-clipboard.js file is correct ?

Comment: yes. It is.....

Comment: One thing I've noticed is that you have dependencies listed in both your `bower.json` and `package.json` file. I highly recommend using `npm` to manage your frontend dependencies.

Comment: Could you explain why? Also, I remove the 'duplicate'. Doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with this was that i had bootstrap.js included while having angular-bootstrap used, also.

In dev mode this was working just fine but when built, some dependency conflict broke the app. Removing standalone bootstrap did the thing.